# Broader scope of SharePoint community support in SE?

Tags: discussion

Currently, non coding questions are frowned upon by the community on SharePoint SE but as SharePoint can be configured, run, customised, etc without any code from the users. Are we missing and opportunity to be more inclusive and helpful?

Many issues stem not just from incorrect codification of a solution but from misconfigurations, misunderstanding and corporate imposed platform constraints.

Comment: Where do you get that it's frowned upon? Admin questions are my favorite questions!

Answer (score 5):

I don't really agree. The topics here are listed in the help section [What topics can I ask about here?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) where it clearly states that:

> Questions can come from a variety of different roles... **developers**, **admins** and **end-users** are all welcome to ask questions here! For example:
>
> - Programming using the SharePoint web services or object model
> - Configuring your site, setting up permissions, and adding web parts
> - Using document libraries and lists

I for one don’t see myself as a SharePoint Developer first hand. Maybe because I can solve customer requirements with no-code solutions, at least in SharePoint 2013. On rare occasions, I do code too, but preferably Web Services consumed by SharePoint.

There is also a tag for no-code topics, which I created recently, where you can tag your questions. So please use the tag [no-code-solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-code-solution) for questions where you can't use code to solve customer requirements.

Therefore, if nothing else, I’ll be happy to take on the role as this community’s SharePoint IT-pro, No-Code, End User and Admin guardian.

Comment: +1 All SharePoint questions are allowed here. In fact, I think we should pay more attention to the admin and end-user questions because the developer questions can sometimes overlap with StackOverflow.

Comment: @KitMenke thanks! I've started today searching through unanswered no-code questions, trying to answering them making them visible on the start page :-)

Answer (score 2):

I must say, I do not agree that non-coding questions are frowned upon!

We have several very dedicated community members that loves these kind of questions and gladly answers them as best as they can.

The only problem I can think of, and this is just a guess really, is that the majority of the community members are "coders" and therefore tends to know more about the coding side, and feels more comfortable answering questions that is "code"-related.

Another hard decision is to draw the line between what is SharePoint related, and what is not. Since SharePoint to some extent uses almost every available software from Microsoft the topic is huge!

Some questions do tend to relate to SharePoint, but only through other software (like incorrect GPO:s, errors in AD or SQL Server for example) and these questions are the ones that are likely to be flagged as off topic.

To me that is correct, since the vast majority of members here are not AD or SQL Server experts in first hand. There are other communities in SE that has members with better expertise, and therefore can give better, more detailed answers :)